# A variable is affected more in one scene, but works fine in others

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have a game and under the map there is an empty game object with a box collider 2d tagged "void", when the player falls there he "dies" and the script checks if the player has any lives remaining, I have coded a way for the player to respawn depending on the [image]variable

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag=="Void")
        {
            Death();
        }
    }

    public void Death()
    {   
        if (lives == 0)
        {
            GameOverScreen.Setup();
        } else if(lives >=1)
        {
            transform.position = respawnPoint;
            lives -= 1;
        }
    }
```

Now that works GREAT on all my scenes, but for some reason on one scene 2 lives are being removed and if the player falls a second time the lives variable goes to -1 and the player does not respawn and just falls forever, I have checked and there are no second void game object that could be also removing a life, I'm scratching my head for this one as there is NO reason I can think of that this is happening.

Comment: the code is fine, you need to check your scene if the kill zone is duplicated, try to see the names of the gameobjects that the player hits when falling, put this in OnTriggerEnter2D under the if Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.name)

Comment: it seems like your else if (condition) running twice at some point.  you can handle it like 
if(lives == 0 || live < 0)
gameoverscreen.Setup();

Comment: It is possible to have multiple collisions/triggers within a nanosecond. You need to set a variable to check if it is already collided and keep it checked until next time.